# Install specific version of Cordova CLI in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova

I need to do some updates to a Cordova app created using Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Apache Cordova (TACO).

The Cordova CLI version listed in the config.xml file is 6.3.1 and the `cordova-ios` platform version is 4.2.0

When I try to build the project (using a Mac with XCode 8.3.3, I get this error

> Build failed with error Remotebuild requires your projects to use
>   cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with XCode 8.3. Please update your
>   cordova-ios version.

I don't see any updates to TACO in VS2017 or instructions in the Microsoft documentation for Apache Cordova Tools.

Ideally, I'd like to make the most minor version update possible to get my build working with XCode 8.3.3.

I know there is a Cordova version 7.0.1, but I don't want to make that upgrade just yet because I'm under the gun time wise.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't see any updates to TACO in VS2017 or instructions in the Microsoft documentation for Apache Cordova Tools.

You can follow below steps to use the latest cordova-ios:

1. Open `config.xml` with designer
2. Toolset->Check the checkbox of `Take latest patch(requires internet)` on cordova-ios row.

Update:

If you don't see the checkbox in the designer page, you need to change it in the xml. Find the following tag in `config.xml`:

```
<engine name="ios" spec="4.2.0" />
```

and modify it to:

```
<engine name="ios" spec="~4.2.0" />
```

Update2:

If the version is still not update to the latest, please try the below steps to fix the issue:

1. Clear the cordova cache under: Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Clear Cordova cache.
2. Open cmd of your project folder;
3. Type `npm install -g cordova-ios` to install globally the cordova-ios(requires node installed as pre-work);
4. Then `cordova platform rm ios`;
5. Type `cordova platform add ios`;
6. Run your project again

Comment: I don't see this checkbox.  Only see dropdown for Toolset Name, with values for Cordova 6.3.1 or Global Cordova.  cordova-ios is just static text with 4.2.0

Comment: Please try modify the engine tag in config.xml as I mentioned in the update.

Comment: Thanks for the help...But, I have checked the box to take the latest patch for  cordova-ios (it actually changes the 4.2.0 to ~4.2.0)...Then I rebuild the solution and I STILL get the same error. Remote build error from the build server http://192.168.200.20:3000/cordova - Build failed with error Remotebuild requires your projects to use cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with XCode 8.3. Please update your cordova-ios version.

Comment: This solution doesn't work as I get the same result as Paul.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I've repaired my VS2017 instance and after following again your instructions (Update2) this issue has gone. But now I have a new one: Remote build error from the build server http://192.168.243.132:3000/cordova - Build failed with error cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function. - Do you have any idea what it means? This is so frustrating, please help!

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, please install iOS@4.3.1. This is the only version i found working with XCode 8.3.3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, follow this steps :

1- If not installed yet, install  [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/)

2- Install the latest version of cordova or anyother:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

3- Install taco-cli:

```
npm install -g taco-cli
```

4- Configure taco-cli :

```
taco remote add ios
```

(respond a few question, MAC IP, Port,etc...)

5- in your root project add or edit a file named "taco.json", add inside :

```
{
    "cordova-cli": "7.1.0"
}
```

Where 7.1.0 correspond to your cordova version (`cordova --v`)

6- Try to emulate on your MAC:

```
taco emulate ios
```

You will maybe have an error about platform. Ignore it

7- Close then open Visual Studio

8- On Visual Studio open the config.xml UI EDITOR and change the toolset name with

> Global cordova
>   [image]

9- Build using Visual Studio.

If it doesn't work, please let me know

Comment: I've literally followed your instructions and this is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4utc.jpg

Comment: Do you really have a file taco.json as in step 5? Do you have an error step 6?

Comment: Yes I do. Even this user Reymonreyes85 wrote a comment reporting the same error I'm facing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/installation

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the authority to add a comment to the answer above, so adding my updates here:

If the version is still not update to the latest, please try the below steps to fix the issue:

First, modify your project config.xml file using an editor, rather than through the tools.  Not sure why it was necessary, but this was the key difference from the above instructions.  I also found that 4.3.1 was best.  Remove any ~ characters before the version.

Then:

1. Clear the cordova cache under: Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Clear Cordova cache.
2. Open cmd of your project folder
3. Type npm install -g cordova-ios to install globally the cordova-ios(requires node installed as pre-work)
4. Then cordova platform rm ios
5. Type cordova platform add ios
6. Run your project again

If the cordova command in steps 4 and 5 doesn't work, add the cordova bin directory to you path.  In my case

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\ad0a0856\taco-toolset-6.3.1\node_modules.bin\