# Install version cordova-ios 4.3.0 for visual studio and issue with cordova command not existing in CLI

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2017, command-line-interface, visual-studio-cordova

Someone has asked the exact question I need [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202885/install-specific-version-of-cordova-cli-in-visual-studio-2017).

However, as I am new, my rep will not allow me to comment yet! So I have had to create a new question.

A guy in the question linked above suggests to "Type `cordova platform add ios;`". So there I suppose is where my question is different.

When I type Cordova in cmd prompt, I get a message saying "cordova is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

**Update**: Please note, I have followed these steps: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/cli/ And I am able to run the npm commands in CLI. I was hoping to simply update my ios version only.

I have also looked up PATH but I have no idea where to start, problem is, people suggest that I shouldn't need to adjust PATH as running the CLI commands to install the Cordova CLI should just allow me to use it?

So to summarize:

1. I downloaded the node.js and installed it
2. I typed this into cmd "npm install -g cordova" which installed
3. I type "cordova" and get my "cordova is not recognized as an internal or external command" message above
4. My aim is to upgrade my cordova-ios 4.2.0 to cordova-ios 4.3.0 to fix my main error of "remote build requires your projects to use cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with XCode 8.3"

**Update 2 9th oct 2017:**

I have given up for now with the above, to work around this i installed Node.js 8.6.0 then updated cordova using npm... im now facing some more issues that I am again stuck on and will create a new question.
Hopefully in the meantime, someone can answer this question and i can try again.
I suspect my issues could be relating to the fact i installed VS 2017 and used all the built in nuget packages (for cordova and node.js) and they are conflicting with the manual way in some way (i suspect that, as running the "cordova" command on my other PC worked fine!)

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, but the error message you have copied is because the command "cordova" is not on the PATH in the shell you are running it in. How you fix this depends on the platform you are running on. You are encouraged to consult online resources for making sure that the Cordova tools are on your path.

Comment: Please note, i have followed these steps: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/
And i am able to run the npm commands in CLI.  I was hoping to simply update my ios version only

Comment: You should put details like this in the body of the question, because no one knew you were using npm to run the tool in question until now. But external links are not a good idea. Provide a brief synopsis of what you tried, and what results you got.

Comment: Hello jdv thank you for a quick response.
I know nothing of PATH and what it is... i looked it up earlier today as someone else suggested it, but I have no idea what i need to do.

Can you point me in some direction, maybe what i can search? or if you can let me know how to "add cordova to my PATH shell" and how i "run in a shell?"

I running on windows 8.1

Comment: jdv thanks, i have updated my question with my note above

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad for this site. It is not a threaded forum for working through install issues, but rather intended for focused questions about (usually) programming. This question seems to be about helping you get an NPM module installed to some specific platform, which is out of scope for this site. You should start from the beginning over on that Apache/NPM link and make sure you understand what the instructions are telling you.

Comment: Hint: NPM is a "package manager" for installing and managing Javascript libraries and tools. You need to sort out why your NPM environment cannot install or provide "cordova" before you can do anything else. i.e., you cannot run a "cordova platform ..." command until you sort out the NPM issues you have.

Comment: I have followed all install instructions and understand them on the link i provided, but with no luck.  
The guides i have read about my issues say that i shouldnt need to edit "PATH", it should just work.

Comment: Then figure out why it isn't working? This is an NPM problem of some sort related to your platform. You need to work from the known to the unknown and sort it out. Do any other NPM module commands work? Why? Why not? BTW, I mentioned the PATH because you **never mentioned NPM** in your original question.

Comment: What does `npm ls` give you? Are the results expected? What other NPM commands would you use to inquire into the state of modules?

Comment: I first use: "npm install -g cordova" which works and i see it showing it being installed (in the guide link above),  Then i can run "npm update -g cordova" to update, which works, and also to check version "npm info cordova version" which correctly shows me the version.

running "npm ls" returns the following:
c:\Users\darren
|___ (empty)

Comment: Details like this **should be in the body of the question**.

Comment: Probably an NPM bug: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11265