# Visual Studio 2017 iOS Build Failed to acquire Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova, taco, tools-for-apache-cordova

I am building a mobile app using VS-TACO and I am trying to run my build on iOS.

When I try to build this app for iOS on a Windows host which is connected to a Mac with remotebuild agent, then I get following Error Message in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows Machine

> "Remote build error from the build server
>   https://macIpAddress:3000/cordova - Error: Failed to acquire Cordova
>   version 6.3.1. TACO0204: Error installing cordova via npm. Exit Code:
>   1. See output for details.    EShopper"

When i do `"npm cordova -v"` on my Mac, i see `"5.4.2"`

Windows OS: Windows 10
Mac OS Sierra
I have given all required user permissions as suggested in taco.visualstudio

Answer (score 0):

Making `npm cordova -v` equals `npm -v`. It returns the npm's version, not the cordova version.

Cordova has to be installed on your **PC(WINDOWS)**.

Could you do on your **PC**: `cordova -v`?
If nothing is return : `npm install -g cordova@6.3.1` or `npm install -g cordova@latest` if you want the LATEST version of cordova.

Then you have to tell Visual studio to use the global version of cordova, for that: choose Global Cordova option in Config.xml editor UI.
[image]

Tell me if it's better, otherwise i'll guide you.

Comment: Aldwen, Thank you for reply. I am off and will return to office on 8th. I got my Windows 10 machine checked and  in that machine:                                                                               cordova -v gave "'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."                                                                 npm -v gave "'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."                                                              Will install and let you know soon.Thanks again.

Comment: thank you for the link. Little confused. Link shared is for node installation on mac. Should node and Cordova be installed both Windows 10 and Mac 10.12?

Comment: Only on Windows! But it doesn't matter if it's installed on MAC

Comment: Hi Aldwen, thanks i came out of that step.                                                                       Post installing node and cordova on my Windows machine, i was getting following error. "Build failed with error Remotebuild requires your projects to use cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with XCode 8.3. Please update your cordova-ios version."

Comment: So, i told Visual studio to use the global version of cordova as suggested above. I could see VS-RemoteBuild communicating. I was trying to run my application which is just a plain blank application with some prints in JS. Now, VS Complains of following error.                                                                        Error MSB4018 The "VsTac" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Siva\AppData\Local\Temp\appAsTgz.tgz'.

Comment: Ok, normal, follow this steps on your windws computer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202885/install-specific-version-of-cordova-cli-in-visual-studio-2017/47100179#47100179

Comment: Thanks Aldwen, i tried steps you suggested in shared link. Step-6 "taco emulate ios" is giving error. Error is "------ Incremental Build: false
C:\Users\Siva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\taco-cli\node_modules\applicationinsights\AutoCollection\Exceptions.js:25 throw error;
 Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open 'C:\Users\Siva\AppData\Local\Comms\UnistoreDB\USS.jtx'.I made sure the user permissions are proper in mac for /usr//local/bin.Though application has got nothing to do,I tried cleaning the solution, removing platforms folder, using global cordova in config. Please help

Comment: Fix for the above one is: I had to run the powershell as administrator. Once after issuing "taco emulate ios", there is a long wait. After wait, the issue i see now is                                                                                                                  ------ Incremental Build: false
TACO5629: Remote build failed
Inner Error:
Failed to parse changed files needed to prepare a build patch

Comment: Could you now try to build using visual studio?

Comment: Building from VS gave "Build failed with error Remotebuild requires your projects to use cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with XCode 8.3. Please update your cordova-ios version"                                                                                                   Followed steps in shared link and did follwing:                                                         C:\Users\Siva\source\repos\EShopper\EShopper>npm install -g cordova-ios
+ cordova-ios@4.5.3
added 50 packages in 18.091s

Comment: Post that, did C:\Users\Siva\source\repos\EShopper\EShopper>cordova platform rm ios
C:\Users\Siva\source\repos\EShopper\EShopper>cordova platform add ios
WARNING: Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS - win32.
Adding ios project...
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
        Path: platforms\ios
        Package: io.cordova.myapp7a6666
        Name: EShopper
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.2.1
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios

Comment: Running from VS is again giving this same error: Build failed with error Remotebuild requires your projects to use cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with XCode 8.3. Please update your cordova-ios version

Comment: In config.xml, i did <engine name="ios" spec="~4.2.0" />.                                         when i do "npm install -g cordova-ios" it shows "+ cordova-ios@4.5.3". I dont understand why "cordova platform add ios" is creating project  with cordova-ios@4.2.1.

Comment: Same issue for me.

Comment: Here is a piece of my config.xml: 
 <preference name="deployment-target" value="7.1.2" />
  <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.2" />

Comment: In cmd go in your projet folder and type this commands: 
cordova platforms rm ios Then cordova platforms add ios@4.5.1

Comment: 4.5.2 version of ios platform has a bug with image. Use  4.5.1 instead!

Comment: <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.1" /> and <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.2" />cordova platforms add ios@4.5.1 is giving error "Error: cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function".  Deleting "platforms"  folder and redoing did not help.                                      Online surf for this error and suggestion in "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0n4N92sE8Zo" did not help.                                                     May i know what is deployment-target value in <preference name="deployment-target" value="7.1.2" />

Comment: 7.1.2 is the minumum version of ios your app will support.
Wich version of cordova do you use? And Wich version of node?

Comment: iOS : macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6,                                                                     Cordova : 6.3.1,                                                                                                   Node: v8.9.1

Comment: cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is due to your version of cordova. Upgrade your cordova. 
npm uninstall -g cordova then npm install -g cordova@7.1.0

Comment: @Aldwen i see this issue in "taco emulate ios". I am running remotebuild in secure mode in my mac. Could you please tell me what is that i am missing here: C:\WINDOWS\system32>taco emulate ios ------ Incremental Build: false TACO5629: Remote build failed Inner Error: Failed to parse changed files needed to prepare a build patch

Comment: You are in system32 folder! Go in your project folder and try again

Comment: "taco remote add ios" had to be run from system32 in order to succeed.           "taco emulate ios" gave warning "developmentTeam is missing from your build.json". To address this i included ` "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "release": {
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXXXXXX",
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer"
    }` Build Succeeded

Comment: But, now the problem is **TACO5616: Http 404: Error from attempting to emulate: Command failed: ios-sim launch /Users/siva.nernur/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/36981/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator/io.cordova.myapp7a6666.app --devicetypeid 'iPhone-5' --exit
No available runtimes could be found for "iPhone 5".** remotebuild is showing log **GET /cordova/build/36981/emulate?target= 404 803.051 ms - 1286**  @Aldwen thanks for constant help. hope i am close to see the app on ios emulator in mac.

Comment: Can someone please suggest how can i fix the above issue and bring up my app on simulator

Comment: Siva, did you try to build from Visual studio  recently?

Comment: I had the same issue than you, yousing command line, but it works on Visual studio.

Comment: yeah, tried from Visual Studio. Did not work!!  hey @Aldwen, as i cannot ask your mail id here, i am sharing mine. "siva.nernur@gmail.com". Please let me know if you are open to get in touch and give sometime to help me fixing this on Teamviewer.  Thank you!