# VS2017 Cordova build error Remotebuild requires your projects to use cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with XCode 8.3

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

```
My MacOS X env:  
cordova -v: 7.1.0  
remotebuild -v: Copyright (C) 2014-2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 2.1.3  
MacOS High Sierra (10.13.1)  
Xcode: 9.1  

My Window 10 Pro (ver 1709) dev env:  
Visual Studio Community 2017: ver 15.4.4  
Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova: 15.0.26728  
Cordova Toolset (set by VS 2017):  
Cordova 6.3.1  
node.js: 4.4.3  
cordova-simulate: 0.3.1.2  
cordova-ios: 4.2.0
```

Microsoft Cordova documentation has not caught up with VS2017 and latest Cordova versions.

When in VS2017 on Wins10 PC, building to iOS and to any Simulator - [iOS device] target, I get the following error in full:

> 'Remote build error from the build server https://[my mac
>   ip]:3000/cordova - Build failed with error Remotebuild requires your
>   projects to use cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with XCode 8.3. Please
>   update your cordova-ios version.'

Doesn't work to simply bump up cordova-ios: 4.2.0 to 4.3.0 or greater in project's config.xml file. Not even sure what  represents. Cordova iOS platform version?

Please help get me past this build error.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question of:

[Install specific version of Cordova CLI in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202885/install-specific-version-of-cordova-cli-in-visual-studio-2017)

Which notes a suitable solution.

Comment: Pretty screwy the way stackoverflow handles know duplicates where I have to resort to this.