# Build failed with error Remotebuild requires your projects to use cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with Xcode 8.3. Please update your cordova-ios version

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova

I am aiming to deploy a mobile application to the iOS platform using codes developed in Visual Studio for an Android phone. I am unable to open the Visual Studio file on my Macbook (macOS High Sierra ver.10.13.6) as Visual Studio here does not seem to support .jsproj files. As such, I have attempted following the instructions in the link below to run a remotebuild on my mac while debugging codes and seeing an iOS simulator on my Windows computer.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/ios-guide?view=toolsforcordova-2017#run-on-simulator

I was able to get the remotebuild running, however, I came across the error where it required my projects to use cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with Xcode 8.3. As my windows computer does not have Xcode, I turned to my macbook and tried updating and adding the Cordova iOS platform through the terminal, where it said "Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project." I have searched the error up and it said that it required my Visual Studio project to be open, which I am unable to do so as my file is not supported in the Mac version of Visual Studio.

The iOS version in my Windows Visual Studio is currently 4.2.0 and I am unsure how to get about updating it. I have seen the link below but in only applies to Macbook, where I cannot open the Visual Studio project file.

[Install specific version of Cordova CLI in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202885/install-specific-version-of-cordova-cli-in-visual-studio-2017)

I have installed node.js as well as Git, also attempting to include/update the Cordova iOS platform through the command prompt (Once again unsure if that was the method, but I tried), however, the command prompt did not recognise the update to cordova. Under the toolset in Visual Studio, I have tried ticking on the checkbox under Cordova platforms to take the latest patch, where ~4.2.0 appears, but still does not update.

I am still new to coding and things seem very foreign to me, if I have missed out anything vital or am doing something fatally wrong, please do enlighten me.